# change attrib value while ET.iterpase() through XML.osm in python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to write a new attribute value of an XML element while it is being `ET.interparse()` in a `for` loop. Suggestions on how to do this?

I want to avoid opening the whole XML file because it is quite large, which is why I am only opening a single element at the start event at one time.

here is the code that I have:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

def main_function:
    osmfile = 'sample.osm'
    osm_file = open(osmfile, 'r+')
    for event, elem in ET.interparse(osm_file, events=('start',)):
        if elem.tag == 'node':
            for tag in elem.iter('tag'):
                if is_addr_street_tag(tag):  # Function returns boolean
                    cleaned_street_name = cleaning_street(tag.attrib['v'])  # Function returns cleaned street name

                    ##===================================================##
                    ## Write cleaned_street_name to XML tag attrib value ##
                    ##===================================================##

        osm_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BLUF: Apparently it is not possible to do that without opening the whole XML file and then later rewriting the whole XML file.

1) You can not write the attribute back to the element (although you actually can but it would be difficult, time consuming, and inelegant)

2) "It is physically impossible to replace a text in a file with a shorter or longer text without rewriting the entire file. (The very only exceptions being "exactly the same length text" and "the data is at the very end".)"

Here is the comment from usr2564301 on a question related to yours about changing an attribute value of an element without opening the whole XML document.

> That cannot possibly work. The XML handling is unaware that the data came from a file and so it cannot "write back" the changed value at the exact same position in the file. Even if it could: it is physically impossible to replace a text in a file with a shorter or longer text without rewriting the entire file. (The very only exceptions being "exactly the same length text" and "the data is at the very end".) – usr2564301

Comment: and if usr2564301 is right then #2 is kills this question.